# Jquery get value of select no show right

Tags: jquery, onchange

I try get the value of select field , i use one function activate with the event onchange and inside i need get the value of select , i put here example :

```
<select name='sel_country' id='testsel' onchange="loaddiver('region','this.val()');">
```

I try works , but no get insert value inside function loaddiver

Only get as value **this.val()** and no the real value

Comment: Try with changing `'this.val()'` to `this.value` without 'quotes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JQuery, use

```
$(this).val()
```

as your argument. e.g.

```
<select name='sel_country' id='testsel' onchange="loaddiver('region', $(this).val());">
```

Otherwise, go with the suggestion in the comments of

```
this.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#testsel').change(function(){
    alert(this.val());
});
```

[Jquery Change Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)